# Mysql server has gone away in rails when the database is in a faraway data center

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, latency

We have two data centers located across the globe. if we run the rails app in one datacenter and point to the database located in the other data center. The app throws

```
MySQL server has gone away
```

like once in every 5-6 web request. and show 5000 internal server error

but if we put both the app and the mysql db in the same datacenter. it runs just fine.
It appears to be some latency issue. maybe some timeout or reconnection to the database required. But not sure how to fix it.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Setup a ping trace (if possible for a hour or so), and see if the latency shows there as well. Its not a solution but it might point you in the direction. If any latency ask your hosting company if there is something they can do.

Comment: I saw that issue when the same connection object was being used across multiple ruby processes. I think you must have ruled out such possibilities already. Just mentioning for verification.